# VBA Excel: ListBox scrolling automatically

Tags: excel, vba, autoscroll

I'm trying to make it such that the `ListBox` will auto-scroll to the newest entry upon input via the `commandbutton`:

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    TextBox1.Text = "newentry"
    ListBox1.AddItem TextBox1.Value
    ListBox1.TopIndex = ListBox1.Item.Count - 1
End Sub
```

I'll get a compile error for this. I've tried various syntax combinations to no avail.

Appreciate the help for this.

Answer (score 1):

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    TextBox1.Text = "newentry"
    ListBox1.AddItem TextBox1.Value
    ListBox1.TopIndex = ListBox1.ListCount - 1    
End Sub
```

Answered my own question, hope this helps someone too!